# How to fix error "Cannot index with multidimensional key"?

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to drop three columns from a data frame. My data frame is called "voting". The three columns are called "Total population", "Report Not Registered Number", and "Report Not Voted Number". This is my code:

```
voting.drop(['Total population', 'Report Not Registered Number', 'Report Not Voted Number'], axis=1)]
```

I expected this to remove these columns from my graph but I just kept getting the error "Cannot index with multidimensional key". I'm not really sure what that means, so could someone let me know how they think I could fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As suggested in [ask] and [mre], please provide a representative sample of input data so that others may reproduce the problem, ideally a constructor such as the output of `print(df.to_dict())`.

Comment: for starters I think there is an extra unmatched ] in your code can you take a look and fix it re-run your code and then post the error again, you can reply to me with @my-name and I will help you out with a code and answer

Comment: `drop` does not by default remove columns in-place. Are you using `voting = voting.drop(['Total population', ...`